# Gradle Sync Error - Importing Gradle Project into Android Studio from Unity

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, unity-game-engine

The Error:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection

I'm trying to import my Unity Android Gradle Export into Android Studio so I can modify my androidmanifest manually. This app is very simple, only asking for "anykeyDown", plays a short audio clip on loop, and has 1 UI text element. While the project is importing I run into this Gradle Sync Issues error and I'm pretty stumped.

It offers these three solutions:
- Re-download dependencies. Doesn't work.
- Stop Gradle build processes and restart. Doesn't work.
- Your project may be using a 3rd party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or version of Gradle requested by the project.

The last suggestion could be the key, but I've looked at a few workflows for Unity to Android Studio and they don't address this issue.

There is currently a bug in Unity 5.6 that makes it incompatible with the latest Android SDK Tools and it is necessary to use an older version of those tools to export the project. I wonder if the latest Gradle is complaining because of that?

Any direction would be appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try changing your project's Gradle version from Android Studio project folder.
(Project>Gradle Scripts>build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
```

Comment: this worked for me in latest stable AS 2.3.3 - had too many issues with AS 3.0 preview